Eslint error with formatter in Next.js project
When trying to run eslint in the Next.js project I've got an error
There was a problem loading formatter: /Users/naya/Desktop/work/ftl/ftl-web-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/stylish
Error: require() of ES Module /Users/naya/Desktop/work/ftl/ftl-web-fe/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js from /Users/naya/Desktop/work/ftl/ftl-web-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/stylish.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/naya/Desktop/work/ftl/ftl-web-fe/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/stylish.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

It's important to add that the error occurred only after I'd updated the dependencies.
I see it first time in my life and I really don't think changing that file in node modules is a good idea. Can anyone help me?

Fixed

check you have in eslint config parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"
remove yarn.lock
reinstall dependencies


Exactly the same issue, but in this time was a Nest JS project that I installed 'lint-staged`.
This solution worked for me
